# Oracle to_char conversion causing hour offset?

Tags: t-sql, plsql

I want to run this issue by those who know more about PL/SQL and T-SQL than I do. Below is some code that I inherited and it's returning dates that are 1 hour off. When I remove the "to_char(i.UPDATE_DT, ''YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3'')" in the select statement of the remote query the hour offset goes away. I'm worried about other impacts this change could have, so my question is why would someone convert an Oracle time to a string via an OpenQuery and then use T-SQL convert in the select statement? What am I missing here and why would the to_char cause an offset (if it is the reason)?

```
SELECT
    CSE_ID                         AS ID,
    OTHR_CSE_ID                   AS Case_Num,
    convert(datetime,UPDATE_DT,121) AS Export_Time
FROM
    OpenQuery( OracleTbl, '
    SELECT c.CSE_ID, r.OTHR_CSE_ID, to_char(i.UPDATE_DT,''YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3'') UPDATE_DT 
    FROM AE_CSES c
    INNER JOIN CSES i ON i.CASE_ID = c.CSE_ID AND i.ACTION_CD = ''INS''
    INNER JOIN OTH_CSE_REFS r ON r.CSE_ID = c.CSE_ID AND r.OTH_CS_REF_SEQ_NBR = 1 AND r.OTHER_SOURCE_TYPE = ''SIE''
    ') AS i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplistic answer but; Daylight savings issue between one server and the other?

Comment: That was the first thing I thought... but what's strange is that removing the to_char function also removes the offset, which doesn't seem related to daylight savings, but I'm not sure yet.

Comment: well, the to_char is being submitted to the oracle server to process so it will be dependent on that time setting. the tsql conversion will be done by sql server which will have to interpret the string its given as a datetime before it converts it for its own purposes. Theres an opportunity there for SQL to get the wrong timezone when it interprets the string. Try getting oracle to output the zone part of the string too

Comment: Ok, I should have added that this issue also happens when I run the remote query in Oracle developer on its own, so removing the to_char on the Oracle side alone also produces the offset, which is even stranger. But the time zones do match between SQL and Oracle.